# Can you identify this 6' tall plant?

Tags: identification

Plant is over 6' tall, 6' wide.  Tendrils with seeds and has a slight odor of burnt coffee. Initially ID as peanut, but does not look like a peanut plant.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Given that we are presented with a pod containing seeds and what appears to be an even-pinnate leaf we might narrow the possibilities to the pea family, and only part of that family given that it is paripinnate. So we might think in terms of [Caragana arborescens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caragana_arborescens) or Siberian peashrub.

Check the description for this plant and see if the detail fits; check for flower fragrance and whether the pod naturally split open of its own twisting accord. You might mention where roughly the plant is which will help to pin it down.

Answer (score 3):

It could also be a *Senna hebecarpa* or [another species of senna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senna_(plant)). The lack of multiple blooms at the same time indicates against this ID however, although it is late in the season, too, when some plants tend to become more variable.

The easiest way to tell senna and caragana apart is by growth habit. Caragana is a shrub, so if the stems are woody, then you have a peashrub. If they're not woody and die-back in the fall, then you have a Senna.